# MW8004 Kony Exception

Tags: temenos-quantum

After Calling post-processor in service i am getting following error.
MW8004: Error occurred while invoking the post processor:
I tried without post-processor then service is working fine.
In post processor class just printing log using log4j.
No logic written in code so I am sure there is no compilation error will come.

Comment: Finally found solution for this error .    
This error indicates that something wrong in your pre/post processor.
Unable to invoke the method on pre/post processors or the Java services.
solution is as below
1)Remove the application jar from the application server libraries.
2) Check if the latest application jar is present. 
3)and Also, check if there is no class conflict in the logs.